# In HTTP communication does server know client's IP address to send the response?

Tags: http, tcp, client-server

Once client sends an HTTP request to server, it disconnects from the server and waits for a response. Does server store clients IP and mac address to send the response? Is the clients information stored when the TCP/IP connection is established?

Comment: No it doesn't. It remains connected, and the response is sent back down the same connection. No need for the HTTP server to know the client's IP address.

Comment: @user207421 When you say connection, is it the actual physical connection (from client to server via multiple routers) ? I thought when the TCP/IP connection is established client and server reserves some buffer and stores each others info and theres no actual physical connection.

Comment: Eh? Nobody said anything about physical connections. You wrote, and I quote, 'it disconnects from the server'. It doesn't. We are both talking about the same, logical, TCP, connection.

Answer (score 0):

Every tcp/ip packet has source and destination in it. When the listening socket is created and receives the packet it has the source address from the packet. After that it uses that data to send the response.

The MAC address is in the packet as well. If you are on the same vlan it will be the source MAC address. If you are on a different network segment it will be the MAC address of the router. The source MAC address will be used in the response as well. However, the are other things at play with the MAC address like arp tables etc.

You should read about tcp/ip packets, sockets, and basic networking.

Comment: 'When the listening socket is created' it listens for *connections*. It doesn't receive data packets. Those are received on the accepted socket. The MAC address is in the Ethernet frame: it isn't in either the TCP segment or the surrounding IP packet.